# Which "powered by google" logo should i use?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i am using the Maps javascript API and Reverse Geocoding. According to Section 9.4b of the terms of service, You must display the "Powered by Google" logo. Google provides 2 different images, one for white backgrounds, and one for not white backgrounds.

My question is this, I am using a not white back ground, but its a light purple and the logo is very hard to read. Should i use that one or that one or the one for the white background as it is easier to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logo is only required when you don't use a feature that already contains the logo(e.g. a map or a places-autocomplete already contain the logo).

I assume that the geocoding-results will be used with a map(because it's required), so you don't need to use a logo, it's already included in the map.

Comment: Im reverse geocoding, meaning that its taking my lat/long and turning it into address, and im just putting it into a database. No maps required. id i have to use a map, that makes things really complicated...

Comment: 1. You have to use the geocode-results on a map ->[*geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) 2. You are not allowed to store the data->[*No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content*](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3)

Comment: Right you are. well crap, that seriously destroys this project... Thanks anyhow.